# Pandas read csv infer only bool

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I would like to use `pandas.read_csv` to infer only boolean types in the data.

If I use `dtypes=str`, I do not have a simple way to convert my data back to boolean type as the following does not work well.

```
df['bool_column'].astype(bool).eq(False)
```

I do not want to infer all dtypes as I do not want to lose any integer types in the data.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, sep=r'\s+', dtype={'D': np.bool})`??

Answer (score 3):

For the Latest version, pandas read_csv could handle this without specifying the bool type. Other more clear ways as follow:

You can specify what datatype on what column

```
d = pandas.read_csv('foo.csv', dtype={'bool_column': 'bool'})
```

or you can convert to bool for specific column by applying:

```
d = df['bool_column'].apply(bool)
or
d = df.bool_column.astype(bool)
```

MaxU gives a better solution. 
And Here is another solution:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('foo.csv', converters={"bool_column": bool})
```

or

```
def convert_bool(col): 
    if str(col) == "true": 
       return True 
    elif str(col) == "false": 
       return False 

df = pandas.read_csv('foo.csv', converters={"bool_column": lambda x:convert_bool(x)})
```

Here is my test data:

```
#foo.csv
col1,col2,col3,col4
false,true,1,hah
true,false,0,haha
false,true,1,haaaaa
false,true,1,hah
true,false,0,haha
false,true,1,haaaaa
false,true,1,hah
true,false,0,haha
false,true,1,haaaaa
false,true,1,hah

pandas.read_csv('test.txt',converters={'col1':lambda x: convert_bool(x),'col2':str}).dtypes
#output
col1      bool
col2    object
col3     int64
col4    object
dtype: object

pandas.read_csv('test.txt',converters={'col1': bool}).dtypes
#output
col1      bool
col2      bool
col3      int64
col4      object
dtype: object
```

Comment: `d = df['bool_column'].apply(bool)` and `d = df.bool_column.astype(bool)` does not work when used with `dtype=str`

Comment: i have to use something like `bool_column.map({'true': True, 'false': False})`

Comment: @user113531 May I ask for what version of python and pandas you are using? It seems in lastest version, pandas could auto infer the bool type without specify any dtypes here. But if you have read the csv as str, you could do that `df['cool_column'] = df['cool_column'].str.upper()` `df['0'] = df['bool_column'].astype(bool)` or using your way is absolutely right.

Comment: I am using version 0.20.3 on python 2.7

Comment: @user113531 the auto infer of boolean still works for me in Pandas version 0.21.0 on python 2.7. And, MaxU gives a better solution. I also attach another solution :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have [not standard values - `true` and `false` instead of `True` and `False`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47703471/pandas-read-csv-infer-only-bool/47703920#comment82367610_47703711) you can do the following:

```
df['bool_column'] = df['bool_column'].eq('true')
```